# Copy worksheet from different workbook to this workbook reference problems

Tags: excel, vba

I have two Excel Files in the same folder. The macro runs on the master workbook (*wb_master*). It should copy the sheet from the Data Workbook (*wb_Data*) to wb_master.
My attempt is this:

```
Dim wb_name as String
Dim wb_master as Object
Dim ws_master as Object 
Dim wb_Data As Object
Dim MyPath as String
Dim DataFile as String

wb_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name    'other users could have renamed the wb, so I don't want to refer to the name with a fixed string
Set wb_master = Workbooks(wb_name)
Set ws_master = wb_master.Worksheets(1)

MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
DataFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\Data_*.xlsx")

Set wb_Data = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=MyPath & "\" & DataFile)
wb_Data.Sheets(1).Copy After:=wb_master.Sheets(1)
wb_Data.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

The problem with this is, that in the line where it copies wb_Data.Sheets(1) it doesn't use the wb_master workbook, but the wb_data workbook as destination. I assume this is because when wb_master is called, it reevaluates the ActiveWorkbook, which at this point is wb_Data.
However even though I understand, why this is happening, I can't find a solution to the problem.

Edit: This macro runs in the personal.xslb

Comment: Is `wb_Data` already open when you run this macro?

Comment: Side note: `wb_name = ActiveWorkbook.Name`, `Set wb_master = Workbooks(wb_name)` can be simplified to `Set wb_master = ActiveWorkbook`. Or maybe `Set wb_master = ThisWorkbook`, if `wb_master` contains the above code.

Comment: Nope, it is not open. I tried to avoid ThisWorkbook, because when I do ThisWorkbook.Path I get the path of my personal.xlsb. And yeah this is what I had originaly and then I thought that I might need an inbetween step or something, but yeah... didn't solve it

Comment: Ah, so this code is in the personal.xslb, in which case `ActiveWorkbook` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Sheet From a Closed Workbook

- If you run the code from the `Personal.xslb`, then replace `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` or the appropriate workbook e.g. `Workbooks("Master.xlsm")`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopySheet()
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = dwb.Path & "\"
    
    Dim swbName As String: swbName = Dir(FolderPath & "Data_*.xlsx")
    If Len(swbName) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' file not found
    
    Dim sFilePath As String: sFilePath = FolderPath & swbName
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath)
    Dim ssh As Object: Set ssh = swb.Sheets(1)
    
    ssh.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(1) ' second sheet
    'ssh.Copy Before:=dwb.Sheets(1) ' first sheet
    'ssh.Copy After:=dwb.Sheets(dwb.Sheets.Count) ' last sheet
    
    swb.Close SaveChanges:=False

    MsgBox "Sheet copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks! When I uncomment the line "ssh.Copy After: ... " it puts a space between dwb.Sheets and (dwb.Sheets.Count). This happend to me in other occasions as well - why does it do that? I also get an error in this line: "variable not defined" and it highlights "After".

Comment: @Carina - that's a typo, it should be `After:=`, not `After: `.